# Losing Mouse Events over PictureBox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two panels, one contains a flowpanel containing image thumbnails and the other (which I will call the "imagepanel") contains a picturebox with Docking set to full.  Initially, the imagepanel is hidden.  When I click on one of the thumbnails on the flowpanel, it hides the flowpanel and displays the imagepanel with the picturebox showing the full image associated with the thumbnail.

The first time I click on the thumbnail, all mouse events for the picturebox work as expected (MouseMove, etc).  Right-clicking the picturebox hides the imagepanel and displays the flowpanel.

The next time I click the thumbnail, none of the mousevents for the picturebox are being triggered.  When I click on the image, my mouse events once again operate work as expected.  I don't want my users to have to click on the picturebox.

I tried using `picturebox.Focus()` and `picturebox.Select()`,
but neither of these did anything.  I also tried to simulate a Left Mouse Click using this link, but it didn't work either:

[How to simulate mouse click code example](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/c%23+how+to+simulate+mouse+click)

What should I do to set "focus" on the picturebox, so that the picturebox events are picked up ?

======== **EDIT** ========

My form has a Top/Down splitter panel.  The lower panel contains Left/Right splitter panel.  The Right panel contains the Flow Panel and the ImagePanel, and the troublesome PictureBox is on the ImagePanel.  In the Paint and Click events for the PictureBox, and on the Click event for the thumbnails on the flowpanel, I am writing `this.ActiveControl.Name` to the console.  It *always* shows the name of the Top/Down splitter panel.  Yet, when I add a MouseMove event to the Top/Down splitter panel, it never fires, even though it is consistently the Active Control for the form.

======== **ANOTHER EDIT** ========

I compiled ways of determining the control from a variety of sources.  All of these return the PictureBox as the control with the focus, regardless of when I call the ShowFocus() method below.  So apparently it is not a "Focus" problem.

```
    private void ShowFocus()
    {
        var _C_ = _get_all_controls(this);

        foreach (Control c in _C_)
        {
            if (c.Focused)
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name + " is focused now (ALL)");
        }

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Focused)
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name + " is focused now (FORM)");
        }


        Control fc = GetFocusedControl();

        if (fc != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Focused Control: " + fc.Name);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Control> _get_all_controls(Control c)
    {
        return c.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(item =>
            _get_all_controls(item)).Concat(c.Controls.Cast<Control>()).Where(control =>
            control.Name != string.Empty);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

    public static Control GetFocusedControl()
    {
        Control focusedControl = null;
        // To get hold of the focused control:
        IntPtr focusedHandle = GetFocus();
        if (focusedHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            // Note that if the focused Control is not a .Net control, then this will return null.
            focusedControl = Control.FromHandle(focusedHandle);
        return focusedControl;
    }
```

======== **EDIT 3** ========

The image below shows the Spy++ output showing mouse events before and after left-clicking the picture box.  As is clearly seen, the handle is the same and the mouse events are the same.

[image: Mouse Events from Spy++]

Comment: Show the code, don't describe it.

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to the mouseevents properly?

Comment: I didn't think having to display the change in Visible properties of panels and Showing Console.WriteLine in MouseMove events would have contributed much to this question

Comment: We need to see code that can reproduce the problem.  You claim you have the events subscribed and are only hiding and showing the PictureBox.  That shouldn't turn off the events.  Try recreating this problem in a new project with minimal code.  Show that.

Comment: My PictureBox has annotations (boxes) drawn on top of it.  These annotations can be moved and resized, so it is imperative that the mouse events of the picturebox be triggered.  How would I subscribe to MouseEvents for the picturebox when it doesn't have focus ?

Comment: As is typical, creating a simple application with minimal code fails to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are these annotations just drawings?  or are they controls?  A PictureBox doesn't need focus (by default, a PictureBox can't get focus) for mouse events to fire.

Comment: No, the annotations are drawn using FillRectangle, DrawRectangle, etc.  Nothing special about them.  I need the mouse events to be able to detect if the mouse is over one of the annotations.  When I simulate the left mouse click over a button, it fires the Click event.  When I simulate the left mouse click over the picturebox, it has no effect.  I have to physically click on the PictureBox to restore its ability to trigger mouse events for that picturebox.

Comment: "As is typical, creating a simple application with minimal code fails to reproduce the issue."  Agreed.  The PictureBox does NOT need focus for the mouse move events to work.  I did a quick test changing visibility of a PB while a TextBox had focus.  I could type in the TB while moving the mouse and everything worked as expected. Something else is at play here.  You have to figure out the difference between the minimal code and your actual project as we cannot see it.  If we can't reproduce the problem, how are we supposed to solve it?  Do you un-subsribe from any events?  Create a new PB?

Comment: I used Spy++ and traced the Mouse Events before and after left-clicking on the picture box.  The handle and mouse events are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned in my original post that I was simulating a Left Mouse Click, but that it hadn't worked.

When I use two consecutive LeftMouseClicks, it works!

This is the LeftMouseClick code:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

    public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: That's not "two consecutive" clicks.  That's a down, followed by an up, which is just one click separated into its two different parts.  This still doesn't explain why you have to "click" on the picturebox; it's just putting a band-aid on the problem.  Glad you found a "solution" though.